# If you add <Link rel="preconnect as="script" href="vendor.js" /> and also a script tag that fetches it, are you fetching the data twice?

Tags: html

I'm trying to understand how  works:

For example,

if I'm fetching code.jquery.com via script:

`<script defer src="code.jquery.com" />`

And I also instruct the browser to preconnect:

`<link rel="preconnect" as="script" href="code.jquery.com" />`

Am I forcing my page to fetch the resource twice? Or does it only fetch once and then establish a preconnect to the resource?

UPDATE:

I tested this by monitoring the network tab and checking to see if a request was populated twice. It was not. Resource Hints don't incur an additional network request.